# Bitbucket error when I push with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, push, bitbucket, tortoisegit

Error when I push commit with TortoiseGit to Bitbucket, but GitHub. And when I push to Bitbucket with Git Bash, I don't have this error. How fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same public/private ssh key pair with your Bitbucket account and TortoiseGit?

Comment: I use public key in Bitbucket, in Bitbucket private repozitore. How i can set public key in Tortoisegit? I think Tortoisegit  get key in ~/.ssh

Comment: @Cupcake How i can set public key in Tortoisegit?

Comment: Are you using PuTTY or OpenSSH for your SSH keys?

Comment: When i using PuTTY , in site bitbucket error, when i add a PuTTY key in my SSH Key

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you any further, I don't even use TortoiseGit anymore, I'm just taking educated guesses. Please consider google searching for instructions on how to configure TortoiseGit with SSH keys.